# Wildcard Pattern Matching fails for some cases

Tags: c++, c++11

> You are given a string *pattern* which consists of characters 'a' to 'z' and exactly one asterisk character ('*') behaving as a wildcard. The wildcard matches zero or more arbitrary characters. The wildcard might be at the front, back, or in the middle of the pattern string.
>
> Given an integer N, followed by N strings. Your task is to find which of these strings match with the pattern.
>
> Example input:
>
> ```
> pl*
> 3
> play
> pluck
> prune
> ```
>
> Example output:
>
> ```
> play
> pluck
> ```

Here's my code. The approach is to find where the position of the asterisk in the pattern string, and compare the substring of pattern before the asterisk with the first # characters of the testing string, and also the substring of pattern after the asterisk with the last # characters of the testing string.

It runs almost perfectly, but there is one test case that outputs the wrong answer. I tried to come up with some random cases but it all work as intended. I don't know the case that makes my code go wrong yet. Can you help me find those cases or point out some mistakes from my code? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string pattern;
    cin >> pattern;
    int patternLen = pattern.length();
    int asterPos = pattern.find('*');

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        int tempLen = temp.length();

        bool verdict;
        if (tempLen >= patternLen - asterPos - 1) {
            verdict = (temp.substr(0, asterPos) == pattern.substr(0, asterPos)) && (temp.substr(tempLen - patternLen + asterPos + 1) == pattern.substr(asterPos + 1));
        } else {
            verdict = false;
        }

        if (verdict) {
            cout << temp << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just for clarity, are you expected to not use any regex library which already exists?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen unfortunately no, I can't use `<regex>`

Comment: What is the case where it doesn't work properly?

Comment: @Alex oh sorry for the wording, actually I thought about some random cases but all of them passed. So I don't know the case when it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @possibility0 You should be more concrete when you ask a question. No one is going to make a code review unless you don't specify the problem.

Comment: If you cant tell when this code fails, we cant help you out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a counter-case:

```
ab*ca
1
abc
```

Which should not match, but it did.

The mistake underlies in the substrings of the matching string, because in some cases they can overlap, which should not happen (in this case "ab" and "bc").

Therefore, another condition in the `if` statement must be made to prevent overlapping substrings. The total length of the non-overlapping substrings should be bigger than or equal to the pattern string without the asterisk.

Thus, the statement would be:

```
if ((tempLen >= asterPos) && (tempLen >= patternLen - asterPos - 1) && (tempLen >= patternLen - 1)) {
        verdict = (temp.substr(0, asterPos) == pattern.substr(0, asterPos)) && (temp.substr(tempLen - patternLen + asterPos + 1) == pattern.substr(asterPos + 1));
} else {
        verdict = false;
}
```